# css: filled the box with text except selected area

Tags: html, css

I have here the illustration.

[image]

May I know how can I achieve this format?

A container box filled with text except for the selected area?

Comment: Is this something you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/zHq38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on css `float` property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

You can add an image with `float:right` to a normal paragraph like demonstrated in the this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhvaU/